# How to choose appropriate version of R to work with quantstrat and blotter packages?

Tags: r, compatibility, quantstrat

Should I worry about the compatibility between the latest R with the latest quantstrat and blotter packages?

At the time when I wrote this question, the latest blotter was updated 2016-01-16 15:48:02+01, the latest quantstrat was updated on 2016-03-11 17:31:38+01, and the latest stable R 3.2.4 was updated on Thursday 2016-03-10.

Based on their update-time difference, should I assume quantstrat work fine with the latest R version, whereas blotter may not work well with the latest R? Is there an secure and easy way to choose the appropriate R version for the latest quantstrat and blotter packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to choose appropriate version of R to work with quantstrat and blotter packages?

Use a recent version.

> Should I worry about the compatibility between the latest R with the latest quantstrat and blotter packages?

No.

I'm not sure why you would assume that the latest blotter wouldn't work with the latest versions of R and quantstrat, just because blotter happened to have been last updated 2 months prior to the others.

> Is there an secure and easy way to choose the appropriate R version for the latest quantstrat and blotter packages?

Use a recent version.

Comment: I am new to R and programming, I guess there is a lot of basics for me to catch up. 
The reason why I assume that is the latest R may bring in some new changes which the latest blotter updated 2 months earlier could not know those changes in advance. Therefore, it may cause some errors. 

Or did I miss something important here?

Comment: @Kenny: it's possible, but unlikely. The build/check process on R-Forge runs against R-devel, which contains the latest changes before they make it into the release. And there are packages on CRAN that haven't been updated in years, but still work with current versions of R.